# Javascript not executing after clicking href (only on iPhone5)

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

I have some jQuery in my app that displays a loading animation whilst a subsequent page is loaded. the animation works fine on desktop/chrome etc however not on iPhone 5 - whilst investigating I noticed if I placed event.preventDefault into my code the animation would work fine however the user obviously isn't redirected.

My code is below

```
$('#generate').click(function(event)
    {
        $('.trees').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        progress(1);
    });
```

This snippet appears to work where I have tested it bar the iPhone 5  - why does the iPhone 5 terminate the page upon click without the page loading and also how can I work around this?

*edit* added progress function as per comments below

function progress(stage)
        {
            var limit = 1000;
            $('#hello').fadeIn(500);
            $('#seeya').hide();

```
        if(stage == 1)
        {
            $('#tree1').fadeIn(0);
            stage ++;
        }
        else if(stage == 2)
        {
            $('#tree1').fadeOut(0);
            $('#tree2').fadeIn(0);
            stage++;
        }
        else if(stage == 3)
        {
            $('#tree2').fadeOut(0);
            $('#tree3').fadeIn(0);
            stage ++;
        }
        else if (stage == 4)
        {
            $('#tree3').fadeOut(0);
            stage = 1;
        }

        setTimeout(progress, limit, stage);
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is progress() method?

Comment: that is a function I wrote - it works fine and is unrelated to the issue because on iPhone 5 the whole page appears to immediately redirect before the subsequent page has loaded

Comment: Sounds like relevant for finding a fix. Wait animation to finish, then redirect user using e.g `this.click();`. But quite strange it works on other device, not just on iPhone5

Comment: I can't wait for the animation to finish and then just redirect as the page loading takes a variable amount of time to load. The animation running is purely hiding/showing divs in a repeated sequence so the user knows something is happening. I have added my progress function above just in case

Comment: hi complex it maybe but it works. Never heard that it only accepts two parameters and I can confirm in this case my function accepts, reads and updated stage as I want it too inside of my progress function. the progress function is not the issue even a console.log('hi') or alert('hi') will not work after the #generate click event- the page just redirects on iPhone 5

Comment: Ya, i forgot about extra params passed to `setTimeout()`. You could try maybe using `event.preventDefault();` in click handler and `progress.call(this, 1);` and then at end of `(stage == 4)` condition, call native click method (not jQuery's one) using `this.click();`

Comment: I could use event.preventDefault however the generate button is simply a hyperlink. When clicked the next page begins loading. The progress animation is literally there until the next page is loaded. The issue is the loading animation doesn't ever run on the iPhone 5 on safari specifically because it no longer runs JS once a hyper link has been called